# referencing linq and other variables in HTML

Tags: linq-to-sql, webforms

How do you reference a LINQ object that you have created such as a list, (or any other variables in your code behind) in your HTML? I have seen examples of how to do this using MVC, but I am using Web Forms. I want to do something like this :

```
                    <% if (customReports.Count > 0) %>
                    <% { %>
                    <% Response.Write("hello"); %>
                    <% } %> </code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASPX files are converted by the ASP.NET runtime into classes, which in turn inherit from their associated code-behind. This means that the standard rules of inheritance apply to variable scoping -i.e. if you have a public or protected member variable declared in your code-behind class, it will be directly accessible in the ASPX just like in your example.

Example code-behind:

```
public partial class MyPage : Page 
{
    protected int test = 3; // This member will be accessible from the ASPX.

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
    }
}
```

Example ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MyPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyPage" %>

<p>Hello world, my variable is <%=test%>.</p>
```

Comment: But none of my variables appear in intellisense on my ASPX page.  Can you give an example?